# How can you numerically approximate the geodesic midpoint of 2 points on an ellipsoids?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Assume we have an arbitrary ellipsoid:

$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$

Or on it's parametric form.

We have 2 arbitrary points on the ellipse $p_1, p_2$. And there is some geodesic line passing through both. There is a midpoint $p_{mid}$ as well.

The goal is to try to approximate this midpoint somehow with the information available.

We can easily calculate the gradient $\nabla E$ where $E$ is the ellipsoid. Now, this gradient points away from the origin of the ellipse. If there is a way to make it point towards $p_{mid}$ we could simply follow the gradient down by $\epsilon$ steps, and we will have found a good approximation of the midpoint.

But I do not know if there is a simple way to compute such an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,
this is not an ellipse -
it is an ellipsoid.

Second,
by doing a search for
"geodesic of ellipsoid"
I found an excellent article
in Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid

In particular,
the section titled
"Geodesics on a triaxial ellipsoid"
describes the
solution discovered 
by Jacobi
(an absolutely amazing
mathematician - 
read his biography).
It involves elliptic integrals,
so your problem
probably can only by solved
numerically.

Your turn.

Comment: The quesiton was not "how can you find the geodesic curve on an ellipsoid", the question was how to approximate the geodesic midpoint.

Also if you read the question, I asked for a simple method, because I need to run this gradient descent algorithm in less than a microsecond. I care about speed more than about accuracy